# Can we display Count of Events in a calendar day in Full Calendar

Tags: fullcalendar

We are using Full Calendar Js and CSS. Requirement is to display the count of events instead of the event description on the calendar day. Is there a way we can do that?

Comment: You could do that in the code which generates your event feed - instead of returning a raw list of events to fullCalendar, just return one event per day showing the overall count for that day.

Answer (score 1):

In full Calendar there is a method to get all events in a calendar
`calendar.getEvents() -> Array`
which returns an array of all events stored in client side memory.

then you simply have to iterate through the array and look for events that overlap your target day.
Here are links to the documentation for the method
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-getEvents
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing